# Why am I getting 500 Internal Server Error when calling post rest api via python request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, api, post

I'm trying to call a post rest API using python requests library. I'm able to get a proper response when I request using postman. When I tried to call it using python request library I get an internal server error.

```
import requests

url = "http://192.188.9.146:9886/getcontext/"

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project\"\r\n\r\ndaynight\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"D:\\Downloads\\GTA.Imaging.Services\\GTA.Imaging.Services.Wrapper.TestApp\\PatternMatchingdata\\Go_To_Setting_Screen.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "79668e4b-305b-404e-904f-92fc71a12f9f"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

this gives me error as below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

When I use the postman client app I get output with the expected response 
[Postman client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIdUu.png)
what am I doing wrong?
Any guidance will be very helpful thanks.

Comment: Use wireshark to grab the outbound TCP data from both postman & python, and compare. Also, do you _need_ to put the "project" and "file" attributes into different form sections? Could they maybe appear together?

Comment: Hi, can you share some example done with Wireshark? Yes, I need to put both attributes together. Something like this

Comment: Multipart requests are a built-in feature of the `requests` module. Don't roll your own. Read how to use it: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: If http://192.188.9.146:9886/getcontext/ is an internal app - check the server logs.

Comment: yes it is running in local server , made up of flask

Comment: Wireshark and tcpdump both use BPF berzerkely packet filter. The command line would be something like `$ tcpdump -s 1500 -w /tmp/api.pkts port 9886`. Then `$ cd /tmp && strings api.pkts && less api.pkts` to view the text, or `$ tcpdump -r api.pkts`, perhaps with `-x` for hex / ascii output. Use `src host` to focus on TCP data flowing in just one direction.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any suggestion to fix my problem? @J_H

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `payload` parameter and add `files`. Refer to [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) which explains this option of requests.request function.

```
import requests

url = "http://192.188.9.146:9886/getcontext/"

files = {'file': open('PATH_TO_FILE\Go_To_Setting_Screen.jpg','rb')}
data  = {'project': 'daynight'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, files = files, data = data)

print(response.text)
```