# How to call REST API post request with image and text payload using python request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm trying to send HTTP post rest API call to the flask server. I'm able to do it in postman but How can I call it using python requests module?
payloads are key-project  value-daynight and key-file value- 
postman request is as shown in the image
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8ZMT.png) 
when I tried I ended up getting an internal server error . Problem is with payload i was passing . How can I call it successfully and get a proper response

Answer (score 0):

Just below the `Send` button, there should be an option of `Code`. Under that, you may select `Python` and likewise the sub-options. Check if that works for you. Replace the parameters according to your path.

Comment: see above comment

Comment: @canIfixit, Check the answer on your referenced stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55239385/3748167

Answer (score 0):

Just use your postman request to generate python code.

1. Firstly, click the option named "Code"
   [click the option "Code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzD36.png)
2. Then Postman pop up "GENERATE CODE SNIPPETS"
3. Click select bar to alter the generate code language. (Python support generate Requests code or http.client code)
   [choose language to generate code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T67Px.png)

Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: I tried with that I didn't get expected output, I was getting an error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209659/why-am-i-getting-500-internal-server-error-when-calling-post-rest-api-via-python?noredirect=1#comment97163812_55209659